# Is there an English word whose meaning refers to 'mind' or 'memory', but whose etymology refers to 'heart'?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

I know that the English language has an expression, 'to know something by heart', that alludes to the heart but whose meaning is 'to know something from memory'.

I've discovered that this link between the heart and the memory was something that people believed at least in the 18th century and way before. This originated some Spanish words such as *recordar* 'remember', 'remind'. *Recordar* comes from Latin *recordari* and this one from *cor* 'heart', according to Spanish etymologist Joan Corominas.

So now I'm curious. Apart from the expression mentioned above, is there an English word (not an expression) whose meaning refers to 'mind' or 'memory', but whose etymology refers to 'heart'?

Comment: The *heart* was the *mind*:  "Most of the modern figurative senses were present in Old English, including "memory" (from the notion of the heart as the seat of all mental faculties, now only in *by heart*, which is from late 14c.)" https://www.etymonline.com/word/heart

Comment: From a Comment in Language Log: "Going back to the Greeks, the cephallocentric view had battled in Western thought with the rival cardiocentric (= "**mind is in the heart**") view, with such thinkers as Aristotle (not reputed to be much of a down-on-Western-style-rationality mystic . . .) usually being assigned to the cardiocentric camp, and no one knowing quite how to settle the issue definitively for many many centuries." http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=14807 (emphasis mine)

Comment: @Kris A comment worthy of 'answer' status even though inappropriate. Wasn't there a 'renocentric' view as well? / As many believe in an afterlife, there is an argument that 'mind is in the brain' is better expressed 'spirit-soul complex has a complex association with the brain during a person's earthly existence'.

Comment: Heart is used in many expressions to mean "mind". How about "deep in my heart I know..."

Comment: @Mr Lister In the Bible, 'heart' is arguably used at times for the _soul_ (seat of self-awareness, thinking, reasoning, volition, emotions – possessed by all sentient species), at times for the _seat of emotions_ component alone, and at times for _spirit_ (organ of relating to God – possessed only by humans).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I was mostly addressing the remark that it is used "now only in _by heart_" which is too narrow.

Comment: @Mr Lister I was expanding, not criticising.

Comment: _Mary kept all these things and pondered them in her heart_ [Luke 2:19](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/42002019).

Answer (score 4):

If you're ok with words/meanings that aren't still in use I found some words that match that description.

One is "**perqueer**", which is Scottish:

> Once widespread, this  word may now have slipped out of use. It comes from Old French ‘par queur’, which translates directly into English as ‘by heart’.
>   <sub>[Scots Language Centre](https://www.scotslanguage.com/site/email/id/1837#)</sub>

There's also "**record**", which is obviously a cognate to "recordar"—both words are ultimately from the same Latin word. According to the OED one obsolete definition of record is:

> To learn by heart, to commit to memory, to go over in one's mind; (also) to repeat or say over as a lesson or portion of memorized text, to recite.

Here's an example of this sense:

> Some men..giue them [sc. children] masters to teach them to scoffe and bite at euery man, as if they had but recorded their lesson.
>   <sub>[Thomas Lodge: Complete works](https://books.google.com/books?id=t706AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA665&lpg=PA665), a1625</sub>

Another word like this is an old, now-obsolete (and probably pretty rare—even when it was in use) sense of "**cordial**" also meaning "by heart". "Cordial" itself comes from the medieval Latin word "cordialis". Here's an example of "cordial" in this sense:

> I not aqueynted of birth naturall With frenshe his verray trew parfightnesse, Nor enpreyntyd is in mynde cordiall.
>   <sub>[The romans of Partenay, or of Lusignen](https://books.google.com/books?id=tHhMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1), c1475</sub>

Comment: I love obsolete words/meanings! Nice answer!

Comment: For all that, you could include _discord_ and _concord_ in the sense of being of one/different mind(s).

Answer (score 3):

**[Creed](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/creed)**

> 1. A 2015 movie in which a former World Heavyweight Champion...

O, wrong [Creed](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3076658/)...  Another try...

> 1. any system, doctrine, or formula of religious belief, as of a denomination.
> 2. any system or codification of belief or of opinion.

[Etymology](https://www.etymonline.com/word/creed): From Latin [credo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/credo) "I believe".  From PIE compound [*kerd-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*kerd-)dhe- "to believe," literally "to put one's heart".